# Why can we include equality in the Archimedean property?

Tags: real-analysis

The Archimedean property states that

> Let $x$ be a real number. Then there exits $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x<n$.

Sometimes, equality is used in the Archimedean property; that is

> Let $x$ be a real number. Then there exits $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x\leq n$.

For example, consider the following problem

> Prove that for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $n\leq x$.

The solution is as follows

> By the Archimedean property, for each $-x\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists a 
>   corresponding $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $-x\leq n$. Multiply both sides of this inequality by $-1$ to get $-n\leq x$. Let $k=-n$, where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ so that $k\leq x$.

So my question is why in the solution the equality was also used?

Comment: Definitions are equivalent. First obviously implies the second. Second implies the first by considering $n+1$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: $x$ can also be a natural number, is that why first implies the second? if $x\leq n<n+1$ and so $x<n+1$ so if we replace $n+1$ by $n$, we get $x<n$; is this how second implies the first?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: If that is the case, why do we even bother with two versions of the Archimedean property? we could only give version 2 of the Archimedean property.

Comment: First implies the second because if a number is _less than_ another number, it is also _less than or equal to_ that number. And yes, that is correct for why the second implies the first. Why do we bother with both? I don't know. It happens a lot in mathematics that we have various equivalent definitions for the same thing. I suggest that you just go with whichever definition your professor is using.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: Thanks. By the way, from your profile I can see that we both study at the same university.

Comment: That's cool. Yeah, I'm a first year. Taking MATH 121 this year.